# What is context in Haskell multiparameter type class

Tags: monads, typeclass, haskell

In chapter 15 of Real World Haskell, a type class is defined:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadSupply s m | m -> s where
```

A couple paragraphs later, it says that >>= and return don't need to be defined because of the context. But there's no further explanation of what it means by context.

How does the compiler know MonadSupply is an instance of Monad if only 'm' is an instance of Monad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "context" is just the part between `class` and `=>`, which in this case is the constraint `Monad m`. And it's not so much that it "knows", more that it *enforces* it--writing an instance of `MonadSupply` for a type `m` that doesn't also have a `Monad` instance will produce a compiler error.

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed the part where it said that being a monad was a pre-requisite. Thanks for the fast answer :)